# What is the quickest way to change your current location to your home directory?

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I'm using Linux. I'm currently trying to set my current path location, as my home directory. Anyone have a clue as to what command I need to use?

Comment: What is your current path?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I think you can just type `cd`? The default directory for this is your home directory.

Comment: Also it’s a duplicate of this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259791/how-to-change-the-home-directory-of-the-currently-logged-in-user

Comment: What is the criteria about "quickest way"? inside your program written in C, or in a terminal? And what do you mean by "current path location"? Is it the working directory? Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52158901/edit) your question** to improve it and give some context and motivation.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and badly written (using the wrong terminology). What do you want to change (your `HOME` or your working directory) and where (in an interactive shell, or inside a program). Please improve it a lot.

Comment: Umm, simply typing '`cd'` at the prompt and pressing [Enter]??

Comment: It is one of the worst written questions I have every answered here...

Answer (score 4):

The home directory has two different meanings, which usually are the same. The value of environment variable `HOME` (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)), and the field `pw_dir` given by password related API like [getpwuid_r(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) on your current user id (obtained by [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html)).

At login, the `HOME` environment variable is set to the `pw_dir` and the effective and real user ids are changed.

To change your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) to your `HOME` use [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) on the result of `getenv("HOME")`. Notice that the working directory is not related to your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (which might mention `.`; but this could be a security issue), and each process (including your shell) has its own working directory (see also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)).

To change your home directory (a very unusual requirement) you could edit -with root permissions- the `/etc/passwd` file carefully (see [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)) then reboot your machine (or at least restart some login shell).

---

The bash `cd` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) is doing that (changing the working directory of your shell process with the `chdir` system call). And when you use it without arguments you are changing your working directory to your home directory obtained by caching the result of `getenv("HOME"`).

If performance matters that much inside some C program, you might cache (keep in some global variable, initialized once) the result of `getenv("HOME")` and use `chdir` on that.

If your question is simply about using your `bash` shell, just type:

```
 cd
```

and that should (unless `cd` is badly aliased or redefined as some function) change the working directory of your shell to your home directory. It is done in a few milliseconds (so should be quick enough) at most (I can't easily think of a way to measure reliably how fast the `cd` shell builtin is; you could try `time bash -c 'cd; pwd'` or `time bash -c 'cd; times'` but that measures much more than just the `cd` and gives at most a few milliseconds on my desktop PC).

PS. the use of "quickest way" and "current path location" in your question is unclear and confusing. I strongly invite you to **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52158901/edit) your question** to improve its wording and motivate it and give more context.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm currently trying to set my current path location as my home directory. ?* you can use `EXPORT PATH`.

for e.g Run below command in command prompt

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/user
```

This changes happens only in current session, to make it permanent add it to `.bashrc` file.